# add values into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a foreach loop that goes through a list of items.  For each of these items, I have a while loop that grabs data out of a database.

```
$output = array();

//$reference is a multidimensional array has been passed to this page
where the element `color` contains the color I want.

foreach ($reference as $c) {

  $color = $c['color'];

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM $table where colorPreference = $color";
$exquery = mysqli_query($con, $customerQuery);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exquery)) {
$person = $row['person'];
array_push($output[$color], $person);

  }                
}
```

So this loops through, the first time searching 'red', and finding 5 people in the fake table who like red.  Next, 'blue', where it finds 1 person, and then 'green' where it finds 3.

If I look at the individual results, my first array has "red, blue, green" and my second array has these lists of names.... I just don't know how to add them into an array *together*.

I'm trying to build an array like this:

```
Array
(
  [Red] => Array
      (
          [0] => John
          [1] => Sally
          [2] => Bob
          ...
      )

  [Blue] => Array
      (
          [0] => Luke
      )
  [Green] => Array
      (
          ..etc...       
      )
```

I'm not using `array_push` correctly though - I'm getting an `Warning: Illegal offset type` error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$output[$color][] = $person`?

Comment: Also check the value of $color. If it says illegal offset type, it's probably because it's an object or a null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've worked with PHP, but I think you need to initialize each "color" array that you're going to push into.  So...

```
$output = array();

//$reference is a multidimentional array has been passed to this page
where the element `color` contains the color I want.

foreach ($reference as $c) {

  $color = $c['color'];

  $query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM $table where colorPreference = $color";
  $exquery = mysqli_query($con, $customerQuery);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exquery)) {
    $person = $row['person'];
    if (!array_key_exists($color, $output)) {
      $output[$color] = array();
    }
    array_push($output[$color], $person);

  }                
}
```

Comment: yup, this did it.  Thank you so much!  You need to add a closing `)` to the `if (!array_key_exists)` statement though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
array_push($output[$color], $person);
```

Into:

```
$output[$color][] = $person;
```

From the manual on [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):

> Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.
>
> Note: array_push() will raise a warning if the first argument is not an array. This differs from the $var[] behaviour where a new array is created.